# IEnumerable and TextBoxFor() does not work at same time in view

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

This issue appears only when I use `TextBoxFor()`, not having problem with `TextBox()`:

```
@model IEnumerable<DataLayer.MobileMgt.Brand>

@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

This error appears with `TextBoxFor`:

> The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: Please update your answer with the error you're getting.

Comment: Last line contains error message.

Comment: You should modify your question to make it more clear and paste the full error message.

Comment: My suggestion is to use `DisplayForModel` template instead.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing a IEnumerable type, You must pass the object without IEnumerable wrapper, as you are trying to bind strongly with object. The anonymous type will be consider as Model you are passing.

```
 @model DataLayer.MobileMgt.Brand

 @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Name, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

If you want to do this with Ienumable you can do it by writing foreach as below, but make sure the identifier ID doesn't repeat.

```
foreach(var item in Model)
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelitem => item.Name, new { @class = "form-control"})
}
```

Comment: I want to pass List of objects not single object, thats why using IEnumerable.

Comment: You are not following the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your model is an `IEnumerable`, you need to loop through it to get the model data. The way you're following is wrong.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a[i].Name, new { @class = "form-control"})
}
```

**EDIT :**

Change `@model IEnumerable<DataLayer.MobileMgt.Brand>` to `@model IList<DataLayer.MobileMgt.Brand>`

Comment: I am using foreach loop to show objects of the list. thats not my problem. Problem is a view having IEnumerable at top canot have textboxfor

Comment: Can you try with `IList` instead of `IEnumerable` in razorview.

Comment: THen there may be some other issue. The issue is that textboxfor properties cannot be read from an `IEnumerable`. It is defined only for `IList`.

Comment: I have been facing this issue from the day i started MVC. but today i thought to ask from you guys.

Comment: Without seeing some sample code, I can't help you out.

Comment: Basically my question is very simple. just try to execute a view having  @modal iEnumerable at top  and TextBoxFor  written below. and i am sure it wont work.

Comment: Yes it wont work. Thats why you have to make it IList, because IEnumerable doesn't have the properties for TextBoxFor. Make it IList and it should work.